# Can a machine learning model ouputs multiple decisions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, classification

I've worked with supervised learning models for a while now. I'm quite familiar with regression models (outputting continuous results for a target variable) and classification models (binary or multi-class classifications). However, what happens when I need to train a model for loan approval with the desired outputs as followed:

- If the loan is disapproved, the decision will simply be 'disapprove'
- If the loan is approved, the decision will be 'approve' and the model also gives suggestion on 'interest rate' and 'loan duration'

Can machine learning models yield such outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! You can do that by having multiple output heads from a neural network. [Here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) is the `keras` api for that.

Although, you'll need to have the data for the other decisions too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course most machine learning algorithms can work with more than 1 output layer. You can either use Keras neural network for creating multiple output predictor models or you can use a decision tree from sklearn. it works with 2 output layers checked